# How to define begin() and end() for a template class backed by an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

I have a class whose contain is a 1D double array, and I wish to provide the begin() and end() methods for the iterators without writing additional classes. However, I am not sure what the return type of begin() and end() would be. My intuition tells me that I can simply return a type of double *, since it is an address to a double array, but do I have to implement it through std::iterator to be compliant with the STL?

```
template <size_t size>
double * ContainerClass<size>::end(){
    return std::end(mContainer);
}
```

Comment: You're right, any `T *` implements `iterator` for you (random access iterator, specifically).

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the class definition.

Comment: `std::iterator` is deprecated btw. And you can look at `std::array` for an example of something implementing a 1D array.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel, that wheel being `std::array<double, size>`

Comment: Personally, I think it’s worth copying the class definition template from the standard and implementing your own version once, as a learning exercise.  Then you can do `vector`, which has non-trivial constructors, destructor, copy, move, copy assignment and move assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::array<double, size>`, either instead of reinventing the wheel or internally to store your data.

If you really want to write your own version of `std::array`, keep an internal data pointer to a statically-allocated array, make your `iterator` type a `T*`, and make `begin()` and `end()` return pointers to the first element and one-past-the-end of the `private` member array, respectively.